# How can I send XML from PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to send XML in my code but it also includes unwanted stuff. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        class InfoDB extends SQLite3{
            function __construct(){
               $this->open('info.db');
            }
        }           
        $db = new InfoDB();
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE age=' . $q . '');
        
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml_info = $xml->createElement("Info");
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM members');
        while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
            $xml_member = $xml->createElement("Member");
            $name_attribute = $xml->createAttribute('Name');
            $name_attribute->value = $row['name'];
            $xml_member->appendChild($name_attribute);
            $age_attribute = $xml->createAttribute('Age');
            $age_attribute->value = $row['age'];
            $xml_member->appendChild($age_attribute);
            $xml_info->appendChild($xml_member);
        }
        $xml->appendChild( $xml_info );
        $xml->save("members.xml"); 
        $db->close();
        print $xml->saveXML();
        //// I tried the following lines with no luck
        // $file = file_get_contents('club-members.xml');
        // echo htmlspecialchars($file, ENT_QUOTES);

        //// The following line means no output at all!!!
        // header('Content-type: text/xml');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I get is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Info>
     <Member Name="Person A" Age="23"/>
     <Member Name="Person B" Age="33"/>
     <Member Name="Person C" Age="43"/>
   </Info>
  </body>
</html>
```

But what I need is only the XML bits, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Info>
  <Member Name="Person A" Age="23"/>
  <Member Name="Person B" Age="33"/>
  <Member Name="Person C" Age="43"/>
</Info>
```

If I use the following line of code

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

I get this error:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 4 at column 14:
>
> XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

What am I missing?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, but is this a joke? Consider the first line of your own code (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and compare it with the first line of the stuff you do _not_ want. What do you see? Then go on with the next two lines...

Comment: Php generates your xml directly, so if you omit `<html>` and `<body>` tags from your .php, you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: @arkascha , the first sentence of your comment is so offensive to me that I wouldn't bother to read the rest.

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun Sorry to hear that. I did not mean to offend you, certainly not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1. You cannot change headers after output has started. Put your `header` function at the start of your PHP script.
2. You've declared the document as an HTML document and include various HTML elements, but you want an XML document.

Use the following:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    class InfoDB extends SQLite3{
        function __construct(){
           $this->open('info.db');
        }
    }           
    $db = new InfoDB();
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE age=' . $q . '');

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml_info = $xml->createElement("Info");
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM members');
    while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        $xml_member = $xml->createElement("Member");
        $name_attribute = $xml->createAttribute('Name');
        $name_attribute->value = $row['name'];
        $xml_member->appendChild($name_attribute);
        $age_attribute = $xml->createAttribute('Age');
        $age_attribute->value = $row['age'];
        $xml_member->appendChild($age_attribute);
        $xml_info->appendChild($xml_member);
    }
    $xml->appendChild( $xml_info );
    $xml->save("members.xml"); 
    $db->close();
    print $xml->saveXML();
    //// I tried the following lines with no luck
    // $file = file_get_contents('club-members.xml');
    // echo htmlspecialchars($file, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

Comment: Can you edit the error as well as the new code you currently have into the question please?

Comment: although I still get similar error on the browser, but in my C# code I get proper XML, and that's all I needed. Thanks
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("members.php").ConfigureAwait(false);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);